# How to forget wireless networks from command line?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line, debian, wifi-configuration

Using the command line on Debian, how can make the system forget the wireless networks I previously connected to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the right answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/711634/95664

My adaptation to the given solution with a small python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import commands
import os

res = commands.getstatusoutput("nmcli -t -f TYPE,UUID con")
lines = res[1].split('\n')

for line in lines:
    parts = line.split(":")
    if (parts[0] == "802-11-wireless"):
        os.system("nmcli connection delete uuid "+ parts[1])

print ">> Done."
os.system("nmcli connection")
```

Comment: If you want to forget just a single network, you can see the network names by including the NAME field in the first command: `nmcli -t -f TYPE,UUID,NAME con`

Answer (score 2):

To forget a single network first run

```
nmcli -t -f TYPE,UUID,NAME con
```

to get a list of all the networks. The output will include something like this:

> 802-11-wireless:12345678-31d1-51e7-a60e-3a52e52b4495:YourWifiName

Copy the string of numbers/letters which is the UUID.

Then run

```
sudo nmcli c delete 12345678-31d1-51e7-a60e-3a52e52b4495
```

replacing the UUID with your own.

Comment: This can be simplified to `nmcli c` and `nmcli c delete 12345678-31d1-51e7-a60e-3a52e52b4495`.

`c` and `con` are the same thing, the default list already contains the name and UUID (deprecating the `-t` and `-f` flags), and in my experience the `sudo` is not needed for deleting (I'm not on Debian, though).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your wireless interface is named after `wlan0` but please **modify it according to your setting**.

You could try:

- `sudo dhclient -r wlan0` (`-r` flag will renew or release the current IP addr from your wirless interface).

You can also do:

- `sudo dhclient wlan0` to request a new IP.

Comment: This doesn't remove the WiFi network from known networks list.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nmcli`, you don't need to work with uuids.

First, *down* that connection

`nmcli connection down network-name`

Then, delete it

`nmcli connection delete network-name`