# How to list known networks and forget them in CentOS/RedHat

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, centos

How to list known networks in CentOS(8/7)/RedHat and also delete/forget the known networks ?

*Duplicate question : [How to forget wireless networks from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1015425/how-to-forget-wireless-networks-from-command-line)
The question is specifically for Debian and doesn't seem to be working for CentOS 8.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list all known Network profiles in CentOS,

```
$ nmcli connection show
NAME                  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE  
DisneyWorld           asfas341-8949-4faf-99f0-dgdagagaadaa  wifi      wlp28s0 
docker0               86b427n4-d86b-4bc9-cddd-asfaagagaaaa  bridge    docker0 
virbr0                03b22e7c-10b4-4d2c-aaaa-asfsasafa672  bridge    virbr0  
DisneyLand            450728db-1262-49f2-b660-asfagagagaga  wifi      --
```

To delete a particular network profile,

use the Network Name

```
$ nmcli connection delete DisneyLand
Connection 'DisneyLand' (450728db-1262-49f2-b660-asfagagagaga) successfully deleted.
```

Or the UUID

```
$ nmcli connection delete 98d5c00f-9c65-41b0-a996-1c0aeb995e9d
Connection 'DisneyLand' (98d5c00f-9c65-41b0-a996-1c0aeb995e9d) successfully deleted.
```